# Для чего нужен Timer? Если есть Handler и Executor?

Tags: java, android

Для чего нужен `Timer`? Если есть `Handler` и `Executor`?

С Таймером всегда какие то траблы. То не в основном потоке, то не запускается потому что timer не успел запуститься на 10 милисекунд. Короче просто ужас.

А `Handler` чем то на `Event` похож.

Comment: `Handler` может использоваться только для `Looper` - потока

Comment: `Timer` - это часть java-api и Android обязан его поддерживать,как минимум, ради совместимости библиотек, написанных не для Android' a, что в своё время помогло быстро сманить java-программистов и пробиться среди уже популярных платформ. А вот использовать или нет - Ваше личное право. И в общем-то когда  речь идёт об Андроиде везде рекомендуют `Handler`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Handler` - это фишка только для `Android`-а. С его помощью можно выполнять блоки кода, завёрнутые в `Runnable`, отложено, а также отложено на заданное время в `Looper` потоках, таких как UI-поток в `Android`.

`Executor` - это лишь интерфейс, который по-разному используется классами расширяющими его. Например выполнить метод через `execute` сразу же, отложено или в соседнем потоке, на усмотрение разработчика и того, как он реализует класс, расширяющий этот интерфейс.

`Timer` - класс, изначально предназначенный для выполнения блока кода, оборачиваемого в `TimerTask`, который кстати расширяет `Runnable`, в **фоновом** потоке. У него достаточно функционала, для решения исторически накопившихся, часто возникающих задач, связанных с выполнением кода в фоновом потоке, у`Java`-разработчиков. И эти задачи до `Timer` нельзя было решить **быстро** и **удобно** в пару строк кода, в виду отсутствия среди стандартных компонентов `Java` удобного `Handler`, который существует благодаря `Looper`-архитектуре UI-потока в `Android`.

Это лишь интерпретация событий, которая возникла при прочтении описаний к этим классам и интерфейсу.

**UDP:** Моё личное мнение таково, что с помощью `Handler` можно решить множество задач не прибегая к `Timer`. Пример отложенного запуска и его отмены в ответе [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656656/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B/656672#656672). Пример повтора блока кода множество раз с заданным интервалом по времени в ответе [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/664786/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-final-%D0%B2-java/664880#664880). Пример повтора блока кода до определенного события в ответе [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/662092/java-%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-thread/662180#662180). Пример когда это может понадобиться в ответе [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/666028/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-surfaceview-%D0%B2-fragment/666245#666245).

Если в указанных примерах возник вопрос, то не забывайте, что вызвать отложенный запуск с помощью `Handler` можно и через обращение к `View`, например так `mView.post(...);` и `mView.postDelayed(...);`

Но могут возникнуть проблемы с `Handler` при необходимости выполнять тяжелые задачи в фоновом потоке, ведь использование `Handler` требует `Looper` потока. В некоторых случаях для решения подобных задач использование `Timer` может оказаться более удобным. Но всегда можно создать собственный `Looper` поток, например `HandlerThread`, который содержит в себе `Looper`.

В конечном итоге удобство использования компонентов, будь то `Handler` или `Timer`, собственный `AsyncTask` или сторонние компоненты,  зависит от поставленной задачи.

Comment: Тоесть в Android лучше использовать Handler? Так как у него к тому же есть доступ к UI. 

А wait можно использовать в Hadnler?

Comment: Обновил ответ. А также не путайте - у `Handler` есть доступ не к UI, а к `Looper`-потоку, в котором этот `Handler` был создан (например в UI) или который ему был передан.